# Realizar un update a una tabla con llave primaria compuesta

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Tengo un inconveniente con un update. la tabla tiene llave primaria compuesta.
Vengo trabajando con dos tablas. una es evento y la otra grilla. En evento se hace un registro de todo lo que necesito desde su respectivo controller y tambien hago registro a la tabla grilla.

en el model lo tengo asi para la grilla

```
// protected $primaryKey = ['fecha', 'sala'];
protected $primaryKey = 'fecha';
public $incrementig = false;
protected $keyType = 'string';
```

esta es mi tabla en mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `grilla` (
  `fecha` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `sala` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `programacion` varchar(48),
  `enable` int(11) DEFAULT 1,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fecha`,`sala`)
);
```

fecha y sala, ambas son las llaves de la tabla(pk compuesta)
En un método desde controller realizo el registro, todo ok.
Lo común es que cuando tenga un update es tener esto:

```
public function update($id, Request $request)
```

Para el registro, todo ok. Ahora cuando realizó el update para cambiar el valor mas para la tabla grilla. como realizar el upadte si se tiene pk compuesta.

```
$this->parrillaRepository->updateByArrayId(array("fecha" => $inicio->format('Y/m/d'), "sala" => $sala), array("programacion" => substr($programacion_actual, 0, 48)));
```

Comment: En un update de una tabla normal buscarias (WHERE) el `id` es `igual a` si fuere una unica llave; en tu caso tendrias que usar `WHERE campo1=dato1 AND campo2=dato2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer la consulta directo desde tu modelo:

```
Modelo::where(‘fecha’, $fecha)->where(‘sala’, $sala)->first()->update([‘programacion’ => $programacion, ‘enable’ => $enable]);
```

Sin embargo, yo te recomendaría que tu tabla incluyera una llave primaria autoincremental, por temas de rendimiento.